# To have AWK's `-F, '{ print $1 }' in PHP

Tags: php, awk

I run unsuccessfully

```
$cookie = "masi@gmail.com,777";
$cookie_tripped = trim(",", $_COOKIE['login']);
echo "Cookie: "$cookie_tripped[0];
```

It gives me

```
Cookie:
```

**How can you do the following command in PHP?**

```
 awk -F, '{ print $1 }'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$cookie = "masi@gmail.com,777";
$cookie_tripped = explode(",", $cookie);
echo "Cookie: " . $cookie_tripped[0];
```

Comment: split() is for regular expressions. use explode() instead.

Comment: `split()` is an alias for `explode()`, but is deprecated since PHP 5.3 (see http://php.net/manual/en/function.split.php ). While your comment is valid, it's for the wrong reasons ;-) `preg_split` is for regular expressions.